# JQuery Check HTML5 Required onbutton click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form which I was to have the use view in steps but want to validate each part before it continues.

So for example I have 2 fields in step 1

In step 1 the user has 2 fields:

```
<div id="step1">

<input type="text" name="firstname" required />
<input type="text" name="lastname" required />

<button id="validate1">Validate1</button>

</div>

<div id="step2" style="display:none">

  //Step 2 fields go here

</div>
```

..Then in jquery I'm trying to do this:

```
$("#validate1").click(function() {

    //check if all fields are valid ... if not all valid then BREAK

    else 

        $('#step1').hide();
        $('#step2').show();


etc
```

How can I get this done...if it possible using html5 required ?

});

Comment: You might want to make your question more clear.

Comment: Where did you exactly get stuck?

Comment: I need a condition where jquery will check if html5 required has detected an invalid field so won't continue if this has happen and will continue if all is ok

Comment: google "html5 validation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which `inputs` hold the `required` attribute.

Then you must fetch the input values, i.e. `.val()`, and use a custom made validation function, or by using html5 built in validation methods, to validate each input depending on which `id` they have.

You can disable inputs `n+1` and `n+2` until you're satisfied with the validation of `n` by either making  them becoming `readonly` or by hiding their section until you wish to show them again.